# Как изменить название класса виджета на другой странице? - WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Есть список который выводиться виджетом на главной странице.
от так я зарегистрировал виджет--с классом "submenu"
можно глянуть здесь как выглядит блок списка
http://www.wnero.esy.es

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'СФЕРА ДЕЯТЕЛЬНОСТИ',
    'id' => "sferadeyatelnosty",
    'before_widget' => '<div class="submenu">',  //название класса виджета
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>'
));
```

Но данный список будет выводится на еще одной странице и я хочу другие стили там прописать для списка..

Поэтому возникла проблема--Как изменить название класса виджета на другой странице( например с "submenu" на
"submenu2") ?

Answer (score 0):

Если еще актуально. Чтобы прописать другие стили к этому блоку, если показывается другая страница, вы можете уточнять класс этого списка с помощью уникального класса для `body`, который генерируется WP автоматически для каждой страницы.
[image: Скриншот из инструментов разработчика]

К примеру:

```
//стандартный вид блока
.submenu {
background-color: white
}
//если показана страница с id=7
.page-id-7 .submenu {
background-color: silver
}
```